# Razer Blade 15 - External Monitor via HDMI not working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 22.04

I have a Razer Blade 15 Advanced 2021 model, i am not able to connect to an external monitor via the HDMI port.

**uname -r** Ubuntu 22

```
5.15.0-41-generic
```

**sudo lshw -C display**

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2560x1440 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1440
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f irq:219 memory:85000000-85ffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:86000000-8607ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=2560,1440
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff irq:218 memory:624c000000-624cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with most hybrid graphics, external monitors work only with the discrete GPU (Nvidia).

Open Nvidia X Server Settings and change to the High Performance profile (Nvidia), reboot and it should then work.